# basis-free definition of linear function space topology

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional space over $R$, and $M(V)$ the space of linear operators on $V$. I can choose an ordered basis in $V$ and identify it with $R^n$, and identify $M(V)$ with $R^{n^2}$, which will give me a product topology on $M(V)$. If I choose a different basis for $V$, I expect that $M(V)$ will end up with the same topology.

Is there a way for me to define the topology on $M(V)$ directly, without choosing a basis, only using the definition of $M(V)$ as a function space? Perhaps the compact-open topology on $M(V)$ coincides with the one I get via a basis, but if so, why?

Comment: It's just the weak topology w.r.t. all linear functionals.